# UEFI live USB leads to minimal BASH-like line editing error

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I had previously installed Ubuntu to my computer but had at one time decided to remove it from the system by removing the Ubuntu partitions from the drive following procedures detailed by others. I would now like to reinstall it but every time I try to boot from a live USB in UEFI mode, I get a Grub error with the text "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported." It will not let me get into the live USB menu to install from the USB drive. How can I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: May be this helpful https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that did not work. I can live boot using a MBR partitioned USB, just not a GPT partitioned one.

Comment: you said that Ubuntu partitions were already removed from the drive. Now, Are you trying to reinstall Ubuntu using bootable USB stick with EFI boot loader? Is it Ubuntu 18.04? Did you reach BIOS setup screen and set up USB stick top priority? After rebooting did you see Ubuntu installation screen? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, the drive was created with the EFI boot loader. I am trying to install 18.04. I have set up BIOS to boot to the USB first, which it does. After that, I never get to the installation screen. Once the USB boots I get the message mentioned above.

Comment: How many bootloaders do you observe in your BIOS setup screen? Can you list them? Do you attempt dual-boot? Do you have SSD and HDD? Are you installing Ubuntu 18.04 on separate disk or on the same disk alongside with Windows-10? Is it a laptop? Please clarify.

Comment: 2 are listed: Windows Boot Manager and UEFI: NVMe 128GB, Partition 1. I am attempting to dual-boot with Windows 10 and on a separate 1 TB SSD. This is a laptop, Dell Vostro 5481, 16 GB RAM . Thank you.

Comment: You reported that the installation screen of ubuntu was never reached, however where from the 2nd bootloader (apart from windows bootloader) appeared in `BIOS setup` screen, all of a sudden? Is it `bootable UBS` stick? Did you notice that? Please address me as `@marmayogi` in your comments, so that you will receive my attention immediately! I think we should move to a `chat` session.

Comment: @marmayogi  It has been present since before I installed Ubuntu the first time on this computer. It is not the USB. It follows the name of the drive on which Windows is installed (I have 2 HDs). I installed Ubuntu the first time on the second drive, the one not including Windows, and because of issues, I followed posts online to remove Ubuntu, basically by removing the partitions on the 2nd drive on which I had installed Ubuntu. Now upon attempting to reinstall from the bootable USB I don't get the installation screen, just the minimal BASH grub screen. I have no problem booting Windows.

Comment: It is not the Windows bootloader causing your trouble. That 2nd entry was made by your previous Ubuntu installation into Windows Boot partition which appears in BIOS setup screen. I suspect that the 2nd bootloader is causing  problem right now and preventing you from  installing Ubuntu afresh. Unless you remove it, I don't think you can install  Ubuntu again. Shall we move to chat session?

Comment: @marmayogi Yes a chat session would be good but it will have to be at a later point. I was wondering that. In Disk Management, it shows it as a 500 MB partition of the main drive (Windows drive) labeled Healthy (EFI System Partition) with a blank under File System. When I right click on it, nothing but Help is able to be selected. Unfortunately, that also means it cannot be removed.

Comment: Do you think really `Disk Management Tool` is going to help you, @sas1979? Let us move to a chat session.

Comment: @marmayogi Ok. When would be best?